# Why is a string printed as a unicode character rather than readable text in C#?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, char

I have a string that I create as a get; set;:

`public static string userDirInput { get; set; }`

I use `Console.Read();` to give it a value:

`userDirInput = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());`

and before I go to compare it I print it out :

`Console.Write("read as " + (string)userDirInput);`

Its printing out unicode values and not readable text...

what do I do to get it to print out readable text?

Comment: Does the console's font have support for the full unicode charset?. Try setting the font to one which you know has unicode support.

Comment: What's the input? What do you see? Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: @Abbas you don't need anything else because that all the information relavent to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use [`Console.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx), which returns a `string`.  [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) only reads a single character, and returns it as an `Int32`.  If you were to cast it to `char`, you'd see you are reading the first letter the user typed, not the entire string.

Comment: you are right... thank you. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

It's because [`Console.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns an `int`, so it's more suitable to get `char`:

```
int i = Console.Read();
char ch = Convert.ToChar(i);
```

Use `ReadLine` to get input as string:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I also was the first one to post answer, but this doesn't matter. No need to sorry, it's your decision, just pick the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()).ToString();